# select most recent record if theres a duplicate

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

So i have been scratching my head over this one,mostly because i am on access 2010 and most of the queries i have found on the internet have commands that do not work on access.

```
id    name    date        qty       created
====================================================
1     abc     01/2016     20        06/07/2016 11:00
2     abc     02/2016     20        06/07/2016 11:00
3     abc     03/2016     20        06/07/2016 11:00
4     abc     01/2016     30        06/07/2016 13:00
```

I need to pull out a recordset like this:

```
id    name    date        qty       created
====================================================
2     abc     02/2016     20        06/07/2016 11:00
3     abc     03/2016     20        06/07/2016 11:00
4     abc     01/2016     30        06/07/2016 13:00
```

the created field is just a timestamp, the date field is a "due date". basically i need to pull out the most recent qty for each name and date. the ID is unique so i can use it instead,if its easier. 
By far i've got:

```
SELECT m1.date, m1.name, m1.created
FROM table AS m1 LEFT JOIN table AS m2 ON (m1.created < m2.created) AND 
(m1.date = m2.date)
WHERE m2.created IS NULL;
```

but this one gives me only the most recent conflicted data, ie. the record n°4 in my example.i also need the other two records. any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `NOT EXISTS()` :

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM YourTable s
                 WHERE t.date = s.date and s.created > t.created
                   AND t.name = s.name)
```

I think you are also missing a condition so I've added it:

```
and t.name = s.name
```

You didn't tag your RDBMS, if its SQL-Server/Oracle/Postgresql you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` :

```
SELECT s.date, s.name, s.created FROM (
    SELECT t.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.date,t.name ORDER BY t.created DESC) as rnk
    FROM YourTable t) s
WHERE s.rnk = 1
```

Comment: this one works,thanks a lot. i couldnt add the dbrms because the msaccess tag required 1500 rep,so i just wrote it in the question. i also tried using row_number but i dont have any experience on it and it seems its not implemented on access

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT m1.date, m1.name, m1.qty, m1.created
FROM table AS m1
JOIN (
   SELECT date, name, MAX(created) AS created
   FROM table 
   GROUP BY date, name
) AS m2 ON m1.date = m2.date AND m1.name = m2.name AND m1.created = m2.created
```